# Как сделать так, чтобы на нажатие реагировал весь блочный элемент?

Tags: jquery, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Блочный элемент (#settings) реагирует на нажатие только в том случае, если нажатие пришлось на пустую область. А если непосредственно нажать на заголовок(h1) или изображение, то данный блочный элемент на нажатие реагировать не будет. Как это исправить?

```
<div  id="settings"><h1>Текст</h1><img src="foto.jpg" alt="" width="28" height="28"></div>
<div id="menu">Меню</div>

<script>
    $(document).on('click', function(e) {
      if (e.target.id != 'settings' && e.target.id != 'menu') {
        $("#menu").hide();
      } else if (e.target.id != 'menu') {
        $("#menu").toggle();
      }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас странный код js. Попробуйте такой:

```
//открытие подменю
$('#settings').on('click', function(){ //событие click на блок settings
   $('#menu').toggle(); //манипуляции с menu по нажатию на settings
});

//закрытие подменю при клике в любом месте
$(document).on('click', function(){
   $('#menu').hide();
}
```

Должно сработать.

Comment: Предложенный вами код не такой функциональный, как мне хотелось бы. Смысл моего кода состоит в том, что закрытие подменю осуществляется не только при нажатии на блочный элемент(#settings), но и при нажатии за пределами подменю.

Comment: @user226023 сейчас исправим

Comment: Ваш код не работает

Answer (score 0):

Предложу свой вариант решения

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".jq").click(function() {
    $(".uller").hide();
    $(".jq").hide();

  });
  $("menu h3").click(function() {
    $(".uller").show();
    $(".jq").show();
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
menu {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
menu h3 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: left;
  background: darkblue;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
menu h3 span {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
menu h3:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #fff url(http://simpleicon.com/wp-content/uploads/user1.png);
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 85px;
}
menu ul.a {
  border-left: 1px solid darkblue;
  border-top: 1px solid darkblue;
  border-right: 1px solid darkblue;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
menu ul.a:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid darkblue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  bottom: 0;
}
.b {
  border-left: 1px solid darkblue;
  border-right: 1px solid darkblue;
}
menu ul.c {
  border-left: 1px solid darkblue;
  border-right: 1px solid darkblue;
  border-bottom: 1px solid darkblue;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}
menu ul.c:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 10%;
  border-top: 1px solid darkblue;
}
menu ul {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
}
menu ul li {
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
menu ul li a {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: darkblue;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 220;
}
menu ul li:hover a {
  color: orange;
}
.uller {
  background: ;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80%;
  display: none;
}
.jq {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 200;
  display: none;
}
.uller {}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

<menu>
  <h3><span>Профиль</span></h3>
  <div class="uller">
    <ul class="a">
      <li>
        <a href="">Моя страница</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="b">
      <li>
        <a href="">Редактировать</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Настройки</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Помощь</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="c">
      <li>
        <a href="">Выход</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="jq"></div>
</menu>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Он подходит** ?
[Песочница](http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/ObyyNe?editors=0010) для наглядности